# Split-Apply-Combine on Pandas Dataframe with np.logical_or

Tags: python, pandas

| UserId | LoanId | ContractStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 124 | Approved |
| B | 245. | Declined |
| A. | 233 | Declined |

I'd like to add a column EverApproved. For User A = True and User B = False.

I'd like to find whether an applicant has ever been approved. The df has multiple observations per id. So, if contract_status == 'Approved' ever then I would like to return a 1 or TRUE.

The workaround I could use is to create another column where I  '''is_approved == 1''' and then sum that by user. This seems like a hack. My approach here is failing though..

```
df['EVER_APPROVED'] = df.groupby(['user_id'])['contract_status']\
                            .transform(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Approved' else 0).to_frame()
```

This returns
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What's best practice for a case like this?

Comment: please share a sample of your data and an expected output

Comment: Here's an example to help illustrate (added to the original post too): 
UserId LoanId ContractStatus
A 124 Approved
B 245. Declined
A. 233 Declined
I'd like to add a column EverApproved. For User A = True and User B = False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ever_approved = (
df.replace({"ContractStatus":{"Approved":True, "Declined":False}})
  .groupby("UserId")["ContractStatus"]
  .any()
)
df["EverApproved"] = df.UserId.replace(ever_approved)
```

**Output**

```
ever_approved
UserId
A     True
B    False
Name: ContractStatus, dtype: bool

df
  UserId  LoanId ContractStatus  EverApproved
0      A   124.0       Approved          True
1      B   245.0       Declined         False
2      A   233.0       Declined          True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `list` of the ID's that have been approved, and use `isin` to create a new column:

```
df['EverApproved'] = df['UserId'].isin(df[df['ContractStatus']=='Approved']['UserId'].tolist())
```

---

```
df
Out[368]: 
   UserId  LoanId ContractStatus  EverApproved
0       A     124       Approved          True
1       B     245       Declined         False
2       A     233       Approved          True
3       C     901       Declined          True
4       D     250       Declined         False
5       C     300       Declined          True
6       D     330       Declined         False
7       C     301       Approved          True
8       E     330       Approved          True
9       E     303       Approved          True
10      E     304       Declined          True
```

Note that I added some extra rows just for illustration purposes.